# Subscript out of bounds in R language

Tags: r

```
genBi <- function(rho, mu1, mu2, s1, s2){
  library(MASS)
  mu <- c(mu1, mu2) #mean
  sigma <- matrix(c(s1^2, s1*s2*rho, s1*s2*rho, s2^2),
                  2) #covariance matrix
  bvn1 <- mvrnorm(4000, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma )
  colnames(bvn1) <- c("x","y")
  return(bvn1)
}

#get samples from Z with sample size 20,
getSlice <- function(data){
  Z <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 200) #initialize Z
  for(i in 0:199){
    temp <- data[i * 20 + 1 : (i + 1) * 20, ]
    R <- cor(temp[,1], temp[,2])
    Z[i] <- 0.5 * log((1 + R)/(1 - R))
  }
  return(Z)
}
data <- genBi(0.6, 1, 1, 2, 2)
Z <- getSlice(data)
```

Return with error  Error in temp[, 2] : subscript out of bounds. Please help identify the problem!

Comment: I think the issue here is `for(i in 0:199)`. Vector indices in R start at one, not zero.

Comment: What @neilfws says is correct. That line index should read `for(i in 1:200){`. This also means that you need to re-write the next line, where you index `data`.

Comment: The OP is adding a +1 to `i` when indexing `data` so I am not sure it is the case that he/she wants to do `i in 1:200`. Maybe the problem is coming from bad grouping of expressions in `data[i * 20 + 1 : (i + 1) * 20, ]`. Take care that `:` takes precedence over multiply (`*`) and divide (`/`) but not over unary minus (`-`) and plus (`+`). Could it be that you wanted to do: `temp <- data[(i * 20 + 1): ((i + 1) * 20), ]` ?

Comment: `i` is used to assign elements to `Z`, starting at 0. This is the cause of the error message.